# Order list containing numerical and alphanumerical values (Python)

Tags: python, list, alphanumeric

With Python, I would like to order a list containing both numerical values and alphanumerical values such as '2a' or '2b'.

- Input list : `l_beg = ['2a', 1, 3, '2b']`
- Output list : `l_end= [1, '2a', '2b', 3]`

Thanks

Comment: What is your criteria for comparison num and str? Is '2b <  3'?

Comment: Could It exist data in your list like '2aaaaab' or '2bbbbaa'?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the key for sorted:

```
l_beg = ['2a', 1, 3, '2b']
l_end = sorted(l_beg, key=lambda val: str(val))
```

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) for sorting.